# Can you tame a Lynel?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

You can mount it, so can you tame it?

Comment: Since there seems to be a bit of a difference/confusion in what is meant by tame vs register vs mount I would clarify your question a little. Since you can "tame" and mount the creature, while the thing you cannot do is register it to keep it. The articles I found seem to refer to mounting as the same thing as taming as they go hand in hand.

Comment: @n_palum: Yeah I'm realizing that now with the question. I think what I really wanted to ask was if you could ride a Lynel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it seems there are a multitude of secret mounts (non-horses of any kind) that you can mount and ride around, they are not mounts that you can register/keep, while you are able to tame/ride them.

[This article](http://www.gosunoob.com/zelda-breath-of-wild/taming-horses-secret-mounts/) talks about all the different mounts and explains based on player's accounts that unique mounts such as bears are only able to be mounted, and as soon as you get off, they will walk off too. I won't post more from there as some mounts could be potentially seen as spoilers.

> Horses aren’t the only animals that can be tamed – we’ve seen a player
>   riding an elk in one video. The taming process is the same as with
>   horses, but there are some key differences. **You can’t register wild
>   mounts, which means they’ll be off as soon as you dismount them.** They
>   also have unique characteristics – they may be slower, but provide
>   something else in return. We’ve seen one player mounting a bear. He
>   said he couldn’t make the bear attack, but it did seem to scare a lot
>   of the enemies away, so there’s that.

Comment: So there's no way to trick the NPC into registering my stalhorse? 

Comment: This did not even answer the question. Why does it have the most upvotes? It seems like it could have just been auto generated by a bot.

Comment: @Gerry not entirely sure what you mean, can you elaborate how this fails to answer the question?

Comment: @n_palum: This answer says absolutely nothing about Lynels. It even emphasizes a sentence which has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: You should check the edit history and see the comment on the actual question clarifying the difference between tame and register. Lynels are inferred to be grouped among "non horse mounts" that are mountable or ridable but are not able to be registered which still answers the question. You can get on top of a Lynel, (as below mentioned in this case it's to attack from on top).

Comment: This is a non answer. They asked if a Lynel can be tamed.

Comment: Again, if people read the response and clarifying comments, you'd notice it still answers the question. I explain how Lynels are a 'non-horse mount' that you can ride, but you cannot register which is equivalent to being tameable.

Answer (score 9):

Update: It is impossible sadly... got him down to beaten n blodeied pulp but just alive... froze him n got ontop, another 30 rings of stamina and nope!. the reason it comes up mount is so you can jump on it's back n smack the shit out of it. Sorry guys... this bastard iv been after to have as my own for the last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been dodging his attacks until hebtries his fire blast, then shoot it with an ice arrow. He falls to the ground and you can mount him pretty easy. Still can't take him, i assume.

Answer (score -1):

As for what I found is you can fly on to the lynels and from there they are Easyer to tame if you freeze a horse  and jump on its back it takes more stamina so I think the same applies to these lynels. I have not tested this but I think it’s a good theory I hope someone try’s it . Good luck

Zelda fan

Answer (score -2):

Near to Seres Scablands there is a npc that tells of a story he heard about lynels which says you can ride them. So keep on trying ;)