# How can I keep the Lord of the Mountain as a mount?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

One day, as I traveled the plains of Hyrule at night, I saw a blue light emanating from Satori Mountain. Curious, I climbed up and was met with a stunning sight. A herd of Blupees surrounded a shallow pond, and standing regally in the center of the pond was a blue horse-like creature with four eyes and golden wreaths for antlers. I took a picture and the Sheikah Slate informed me that this creature was called the Lord of the Mountain.

It looked vaguely horse-like, so I snuck up behind it to see if I could mount it. Surprisingly, I could, and it immediately tried to buck me off. Luckily I had a bunch of stamina replenishing food, so I was eventually able to tame it like I would any other horse. After a brief amount of testing, I realized that this "horse" not only had a full 5 stamina, but also seemed to have higher base move speed than any other horse I'd found thus far. It was clearly an exceptional speciman, and I was ecstatic at my discovery.

My good fortune did not last, however. Eventually, in the morning, I noticed some other random curiosity and I dismounted temporarily to check it out. A few seconds after I got off, the Lord of the Mountain bounded quickly away and disappeared in a puff of blue smoke.

I've checked the mysterious pond again and the mystical blue horse creature does respawn there every now and then. My question is, is it possible to keep him as a permanent mount? If so, how? Can I board it in a stable?

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302270/can-you-tame-a-lynel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't keep it as a permanent mount, but you are able to ride it, as you've noticed.

According to [this guide on taming the creature](http://www.gosunoob.com/zelda-breath-of-wild/secret-mount-lord-of-the-mountain-zelda-botw/), while you are able to tame it, you can't register it to a stable.

> Sadly, you can’t register it at a stable, since it’s not [technically] a horse, but it’s a beautiful creature and it would be a shame if you missed it.

According to users in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/5yg0kx/lord_of_the_mountain_what_to_do_with_him/), the monster saddle won't allow you to register, it either.

> Have you obtained the monster saddle? Someone was theorizing that he, or some other creature you can't normally register, could be registered with the use of the monster set, but I haven't been able to [test] it.
>
> It doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to see something kind of funny, ride the Lord of the Mountain to a stable and try to register it.  The reaction of the person at the window is pretty funny.