# Where is the Lord of the Mountain?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Where on the map can I find the mountain where the Lord of the Mountain is?
The only thing I know about where it is is that it's near a shrine.
I have wondered where to find it.

Comment: Related: [How can I keep the Lord of the Mountain as a mount?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/307774/222207)

Answer (score 6):

You can find him on [Satori Mountain](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Satori_Mountain), near the [Mogg Latan Shrine](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Mogg_Latan_Shrine).